# Paddle subscription error. Laravel Cashier

Tags: laravel, payment, paddle

I'm trying to use the newSubscription() method with the following code:

```
$user->newSubscription('product name', 'price id')->create();
```

But every time I get the following response:

> Laravel\Paddle\Exceptions\PaddleException Unable to find requested product.

As a product name, I tried to use its name and its ID (`pro_*`)
I always used (`pri_*`) as an ID plan.

Which of these data are incorrect? There is nothing detailed about this in the documentation.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the correct price_id?

Comment: @MrEduar I have only 1 product and it has only 1 price. I took the price ID of this product.

Comment: The second argument given to the `newSubscription` method is the specific plan the user is subscribing to. This value should correspond to the plan's identifier in Paddle. https://github.com/laravel/cashier-paddle/issues/7

Comment: @MrEduar  I tried using the product ID pro_* and the product price ID pri_*. Both partners give this answer.

Comment: According to the documentation, it is an integer id `1234567` no string like you said `pro_*`. I'm not sure because I've never used cashier with paddle

Comment: Paddle created the second version of the API and all new accounts come out exactly like this. Cashier does not have a new version yet, which is why the error occurs.

Comment: Then you should report the error on github, as it is a library error.